# My texture gets stretched in some places because of solidify modifier?

Tags: texturing

So I have been following this tutorial **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzlRzJpG7vc&t=13s** and I am stuck because my material gets stretched on the edges, see pic attached. I think it is because of the solidify modifier because as I play around with the settings, the stretching goes away, but appears in other places. So I figured it had something to do with solidify, but I don't know what to actually do to fix this. I have already uv unwrapped of course. Thanks in advance! :-)

[image: pic]

Comment: hello, have you checked your UV? maybe share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Not because of solidify, but solidify + subsurf.

Rim between two faces shares the same place in UV coordinates, so that's why it looks stretched, but solidify makes this rim more visible from front.

[image]

I think, the easiest way to solve this is applying solidify and making UV again.

But adding loopcuts also makes it less visible:

[image]

Comment: that has helped a ton, works fine now. thank you lots for the videos! <3